# Facelets equivalent of <jsp-file> servlet mapping

Tags: jsf

Note - This question might have been answered earlier but I am not able to find any note on this. hence asking!

**Background -** I am working on a legacy JSF application which uses JSP as view technology. Now since we have decided to move to JSF 2.2/2.3, we are also changing the JSP pages to facelets.

**Issue -** In the web.xml, we have following mapping -

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>dummyframe</servlet-name>
   <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/dummyframe.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dummyframe</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>dummyframe</url-pattern>
<servlet-mapping>
```

We have converted jsp file to facelet file but not sure how to handle this jsp-file mapping.

We are planning to write java classes which will redirect to facelet page. In this case, the mapping will be -

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>dummyframe</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>xxx.xxxx.dummyframe</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dummyframe</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>dummyframe</url-pattern>
<servlet-mapping>
```

The questions I have -
**1)** Is this a good alternative?
**2)** Is there any other alternative available without writing java classes?

Comment: Start by explaining what the goal is or what you like to achieve, what is in the jsp/servlet... This all to prevent a 'wrong' architecture... But creating a manual servlet is ofcourse doable, but you could also use rest or soap or... all depending on the required functionality

Comment: @Kukeltje. The JSP pages are one-off pages which displays some important information for application. There is no plan to use REST or SOAP as these won't be accessed regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is this a good alternative?

Yes, but I think it would be better to implement redirection in a [filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) instead of a servlet class.

---

> 2) Is there any other alternative available without writing java
>   classes?

Leave dummy servlet mapping in web,xml as is and put into `/WEB-INF/dummyframe.jsp` this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=mynewdummyfile.jsf">
  </head>
</html>
```

or this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
  <body>
     <c:redirect url="mynewdummyfile.jsf"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

or this:

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse" %>

<html>
   <body>
      <%
         response.sendRedirect("mynewdummyfile.jsf");
      %>
   </body>
</html>
```

or this:

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse" %>

<html>
   <body>
      <%
         response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
         response.setHeader("Location", "mynewdummyfile.jsf"); 
      %>
   </body>
</html>
```

or this:

```
<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.ServletContext" %>

<html>
   <body>
      <%
        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
        sc.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/mynewdummyfile.jsf").forward(request, response);
      %>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Krokodilko for the explanation. I think we'll go with option one to convert it into filter as we are planning to do away with JSPs completely.